# Google API - Reply to Reviews (androidpublisher) Error 401

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, jwt, androidpublisher

I'm trying to connect from Swift app I built to Google's `Reply to Reviews` API which is part of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher` scope, in order to get a list of a specific app reviews. I created a Service Account and with that I managed to created a JWT token, then tried to make a GET request to the API, but i'm getting an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "androidpublisher.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.play.publishingapi.v3.ReviewsService.List"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**This is the request url:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/<APP_PACKAGE>/reviews?access_token=<JWT-TOKEN>
```

**This is my request code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let auth = Authentication()
    let jwt = auth.generateJWT()
    
    self.retriveReviews(packageIdentifier: "<APP_PACKAGE>", auth: jwt!)
}


func retriveReviews(packageIdentifier: String, auth: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/\(packageIdentifier)/reviews?access_token=\(auth)")
    print("Request URL: \(url)")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

JWT Token:

```
import JWTKit
import UIKit

class Authentication: NSObject {

    func generateJWT() -> String? {
            struct Header: JWTPayload {
                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                    case alg = "alg"
                    case type = "typ"
                }
                
            var alg = "RS256"
            var type: String = "JWT"
            
            func verify(using signer: JWTSigner) throws {
                //            print(self.expireTime > Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        
        struct Payload: JWTPayload {
            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case email = "iss"
                case scope = "scope"
                case aud = "aud"
                case createdAt = "iat"
                case expireTime = "exp"
            }
            
            var email: String = "XXXXX@XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            var scope: String = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"
            var aud: String = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
            var createdAt: Double = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            var expireTime: Double = Date().advanced(by: 1000).timeIntervalSince1970
            
            
            func verify(using signer: JWTSigner) throws {
                print(self.expireTime > Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        
        do {
            if let certificatePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "k_created", ofType: "pem") {
                let certificateUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: certificatePath)
                let certififcateData = try Data(contentsOf: certificateUrl)
                let signers = JWTSigners()
                let key = try RSAKey.private(pem: certififcateData)
                signers.use(.rs256(key: key))
                
                //                MARK: HEADER NOT USED
                let header = Header()
                let payload = Payload()
                let jwt = try signers.sign(payload)
                //                let jwt = try signers.sign(payload)
                print("JWT: \(jwt)")
                return jwt
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? or maybe there is a step I am missing?

Comment: Can i see the code you used to request an access token using the service account credentials?  #justcurious

Comment: I've updated my question, take a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to send the access token inline as a query parameter. You need to send it as an authorization header.

```
curl \
  'https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/[PACKAGENAME]/reviews' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

The issue is you are doing `access_token=\(auth)` where you should be doing

```
request.setValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

The authorization needs to be in the header as shown above and it needs to be a valid access token.

Have you run this JWT you are creating against the validation end point to ensure that its even valid.   If your code works you are the first person i have seen in 10 years that has managed to create a access token from the service account credentials without using a client libray.  Great job.

Comment: Where do I get the `YOUR API KEY` which is sent in the url? I created a Service Account and an API-KEY, I set the `Authorization` Header with `Bearer YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN`, Accept and Content-Type and still getting the same response.

Comment: API keys are used for accessing public data. If you are using a service account you dont need an api key.  If you are using a service account you will need to use that to request an access token.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but what am I missing with my request? Because I got a JWT token and used this token to call the api, but still getting the same 401 error.

Comment: retriveReviews(packageIdentifier: String, auth: String)  needs to add an authorization header your passing it in the query parm